# Cleaning Data from PDF file

Tags: r, regex, string, pdf

I am trying to scrape data from a pdf downloaded from the link below and store as a datatable for analysis.
    https://www.ftse.com/products/downloads/FTSE_100_Constituent_history.pdf.

Heres what I have so far;

```
require(pdftools)
require(data.table)
require(stringr)

url <- "https://www.ftse.com/products/downloads/FTSE_100_Constituent_history.pdf"

dfl <- pdf_text(url)
dfl <- dfl[2:(length(dfl)-1)]
dfl <- str_split(dfl, pattern = "(\n)")
```

This code nearly works, however in the notes column whereby the text spills on to a new page due to a \n I end up with the code spilling over to a new line. For example, on the 19-Jan-84 the notes column should read;

```
Corporate Event - Acquisition of Eagle Star by BAT Industries
```

But with my code, the "BAT Industries" spills over onto a new line whereas I would like it to be in the same string as the line above.

Once the code as run I would like to have the same table as the pdf with all the text going into the correct columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use the following manipulations.

```
dfl <- pdf_text(url)
dfl <- dfl[2:(length(dfl) - 1)]
# Getting rid of the last line in every page
dfl <- gsub("\nFTSE Russell \\| FTSE 100 – Historic Additions and Deletions, November 2018[ ]+?\\d{1,2} of 12\n", "", dfl)
# Splitting not just by \n, but by \n that goes right before a date (positive lookahead)
dfl <- str_split(dfl, pattern = "(\n)(?=\\d{2}-\\w{3}-\\d{2})")
# For each page...
dfl <- lapply(dfl, function(df) {
  # Split vectors into 4 columns (sometimes we may have 5 due to the issue that
  # you mentioned, so str_split_fixed becomes useful) by possibly \n and
  # at least two spaces.
  df <- str_split_fixed(df, "(\n)*[ ]{2,}", 4)
  # Replace any remaining (in the last columns) cases of possibly \n and
  # at least two spaces.
  df <- gsub("(\n)*[ ]{2,}", " ", df)
  colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Added", "Deleted", "Notes")
  df[df == ""] <- NA
  data.frame(df[-1, ])
})
head(dfl[[1]])
#        Date                     Added                    Deleted                                                                       Notes
# 1 19-Jan-84 Charterhouse J Rothschild                 Eagle Star               Corporate Event - Acquisition of Eagle Star by BAT Industries
# 2 02-Apr-84                    Lonrho         Magnet & Southerns                                                                        <NA>
# 3 02-Jul-84                   Reuters Edinburgh Investment Trust                                                                        <NA>
# 4 02-Jul-84                Woolworths        Barratt Development                                                                        <NA>
# 5 19-Jul-84            Enterprise Oil        Bowater Corporation Corporate Event - Sub division of company into Bowater Inds and Bowater Inc
# 6 01-Oct-84              Willis Faber       Wimpey (George) & Co                                                                        <NA>
```

I guess ultimately you are going to want a single data frame rather than a list of them. For that you may use `do.call(rbind, dfl)`.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer! Can you please explain the regex that you used "(\n)(?=\\d{2}-\\w{3}-\\d{2})"?

Comment: @redbaron1981 fill it in on regex101.com and read the explanation on the right

Comment: @redbaron1981, no problem. It matches `\n` that goes right before "two digits-three alphanumerics-two digits", by which I meant a date.